# Does every sequence $s_{i+1} := \text{gpf}(s_{i}^2+k)$ eventually cycle?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, quadratics

($\textbf{gpf}$ here is the function returning the greatest prime factor of an integer.)

Consider the family of recurrence relations given by

$$s_{i+1} := \text{gpf}(a  s_i + 1).$$

I don't have proof of this (is there any?), but it seems extremely likely from experimentation that such sequences will fall into a cycle for any positive integer $a>1$ and any starting value $s_1$.

e.g. $s_1 = 2, a=5$ gives:

$
\text{gpf}(5(2)+1) = 11 \\
\text{gpf}(5(11)+1) = 7 \\
\text{gpf}(5(7)+1) = 3 \\
\text{gpf}(5(3)+1) = 2 \\
\text{gpf}(5(2)+1) = 11 \\
\ldots
$

---

Does this result follow in general for analogous quadratic sequences? Specifically,

$$s_{i+1} :=\text{gpf}(s_i^2 + k)$$

for positive integers $k$ and initial value $s_1$.

It is definite that some cycles do exist:

$$
\begin{array}{|ll|ll|} \hline
\textbf{k} & & \textbf{cycle} & \\ \hline
1 && 89,233  & \\ \hline
\text{(also 1)}  && 19121,10753313,1241761,3817193,107837  & \\ \hline
2 && 571,2131  & \\ \hline
3 && 2089,10009  & \\ \hline
4 && 5741,33461  & \\ \hline
5 && 3,7  & \\ \hline
6 &&   & \\ \hline
7 && 2,11  & \\ \hline
8 && 19,41,563,83  & \\ \hline
9 && 6197,7109,6373  & \\ \hline
10 && 41,89,103  & \\ \hline
11 && 3,5  & \\ \hline
12 && 181,2521  & \\ \hline
13 &&   & \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

I've omitted $6$ and $13$ as I've been unable to find a cycle yet for them; if a cycle does exist for $k=6$, its minimum value is almost certainly larger than $10^7$.

So, I am asking:

1. If there's a known result along these lines.
2. If not, any compelling argument for or against there being such cycles for all $k$.

I am also interested in whether every $s_1$ leads to a cycle for a given $k$, assuming a cycle is known to exist. For example, it seems plausible to me that many large values of $s_1$ for $k=1$ grow fast enough that they may 'escape' rather than always be pulled down to the $\{89,233\}$ cycle.

I recognize this question seems at least distantly related to Collatz, and thus an answer may be flatly unknowable at this time. If that's the case, so be it.

Comment: Do you mean $s_{i+1} = \text{gpf}(a s_i + 1)$ and $s_{i+1} = \text{gpf}(s_i^2+k)$?

Comment: large numbers tend to have a large largest prime factor. So, if such a sequence begins to "explode", it probably will diverge. Both problems include two variables, I think, we will even have difficulties to solve one of the problems for $s_1=1$ , lets say. I think, Collatz is quite different to this problem since we have at least an evidence that a Collatz-sequence won't diverge (although we cannot rule it out). Here, I would expect many diverging sequences.